# How to retrieve only values from an array using perl substring

Tags: perl

I have an array of some values enclosed in square brackets and separated by a comma and i want a values from that array by removing square brackets and comma. For example.

```
[3,5,6,1,7,9,2,8]
```

My Code:

```
 my $li=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
 my $l=substr($li,1,length($li)-2);
 my @ar=split(",",$l);
 my $a;
 foreach $a (@ar)
 { print/n$a; }
```

I want to get the values as 3 5 6 1 7 9 2 8 by using `substr` in perl.
I have a code for this but i can't understand it is bit complicated can you please any one explain it.

Comment: Why do you want to use `substr` for this? And how do you expect us to explain code we can't see?

Comment: Can you use split? https://perlmaven.com/perl-split

Comment: my $li=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]; 
my $l=substr($li,1,length($li)-2);
my @ar=split(",",$l);
my $a;
foreach $a (@ar)
{
 print/n$a;
}

Comment: So the "array of some values enclosed in square brackets" is a perl string defined like  my $astr = "[3,5,6,1,7,9,2,8]";  ? or not ?

Comment: @DonthulaSravan: Please update your code in the question not in comments.

Comment: @DonthulaSravan: Your question and code I am sure difference is there.

Comment: The code you posted makes absolutely no sense.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just you try this:

```
my $str = "[3,5,6,1,7,9,2,8]";

my @htm = map { $_=~s/(\[|\])//g; $_; } split /\,/, $str;

print "Each item: $_\n" foreach(@htm);
```